# use an array from another js file in nextjs page

Tags: javascript, next.js

I want to use an array that is on another page. I need the array information for the title and meta tags, but it seems that in next js it takes time to load the information, so I encounter undefined at first. What solution should I use to load this array?

(I can't put the array in the same file because I need it in some other pages as well.)

I also tried get static props but it returns undefined as props.
Should I use swr? What is the best solution for seo?

```
import { items } from "../../public/assets/ArticlesList.js";

const ArticlePage = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { id } = router.query;
  let data = items[id];

  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title> {data.title}  </title>
      </Head>
      <div>
        ....
      </div>
   </>
   )
   }
```

Comment: What does the code in ArticlesList.js look like?

Comment: its only exports  an items array @Geshode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using getServerSideProps

```
import { items } from "../../public/assets/ArticlesList.js";

const ArticlePage = ({ data }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title> {data.title}  </title>
      </Head>
      <div>
        ....
      </div>
   </>
  );
}

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const { id } = context.query;
  const data = items[id];

  return {
    props: { data }
  }
}

export default ArticlePage;
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a common component like below: and import on top of the page. Then you won't have any problem of undefined data.

```
import Head from 'next/head';

const MetaData = (props) => {
  const title = props.title || '';
  const description = props.description || '';
  const keywords = props.keywords || '';
  const image = props.image || '';

  return (
    <Head>
      <title>{title}</title>
      <meta name="description" content={description} />
      <meta name="og:description" content={description} />
      <meta name="twitter:description" content={description} />
      <meta name="twitter:site" content="" />
      <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary" />
      <meta name="twitter:title" content={title} />
      <meta name="og:site_name" content="" />
      <meta name="og:title" content={title} />
      <meta name="keywords" content={keywords} />
      <meta name="og:image" content={image} />
    </Head>
  );
};

export default MetaData;
```